# Query folder by name or path

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the PHP Google Drive SDK:

Is it possible to query a specific folder by it's name or by it's path instead of by it's ID?

If so, I would appreciate if someone could chow me how this is done in PHP.

Comment: Look at files.list with a q param https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list